# How do I change an ActiveRecord from marked to be saved to make sure it does not get saved, from within the model itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How do I change an AcriveRecord from marked to be saved to make sure it does not get saved, from within the model itself?

Considering I can have a method run by a hook in activerecord, such as: `before_save`

for (hypothetical) example:

```
before_save :ignore_new_delete_exisiting_if_blank(self.attribute)

def ignore_new_delete_exisiting_if_blank(attribute)
  self.do_not_save_me! if attribute.blank?

  #what is that magic "do_not_save_me" method? 
  #Is there such thing, or something to achieve the same thing?
end
```

### Update

My particular use case requires that no errors be thrown and other models to continue to be saved, even if this one will not. I should explain:

I am using model inheritance, and I am having an issue with figuring out how to let save the parent model, but if the child model instances are blank, (no values exist in certain attributes) they should not be persisted; however, the parent should still be persisted. This scenario does not let me make use of validations on the child model as that would block the parent from being persisted as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should just return false to make it does not save.
Or you set the errors, which will allow to be more descriptive.

For example:

```
def ignore_new_delete_exisiting_if_blank_attribute
  if attribute.blank?
    errors.add(:base, "Not allowed to save if attribute is blank.")
  end
end
```

Note that you cannot send parameters to a `before_save`. If you just want to make sure a record is not saved when an attribute is not present, you should use

```
validates_presence_of :attribute
```

[UPDATE]

When saving a parent model with children, you have to do something like [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), and in that call, you can specify which attributes must be given or when a child-record is ignored.

For example

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
```

will not save a post if the title is blank.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned, I don't want any error's thrown or the blocking of anything to happen, just not save the record...

Comment: This does not throw any exceptions, but adds errors to the object, which will block the saving.

Comment: This will also stop the parent from saving

Comment: Perfect, thanks, it allows me to still validate on select fields but ignore the child model if certain attribute is blank, just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The "magic" is that when you return `false` from the method, the record won't be saved.

In your case:

```
def ignore_new_delete_exisiting_if_blank(attribute)
  attribute.present?
end
```